# Reference a class into another class

Tags: apex

I have a class "object" like that :

```
public with sharing class CalloutWS{
public Date dateEffet {get; set;}
public cls_post[] posts {get; set;}

public class cls_post {
    public Integer num;
    public Date date;   
    public cls_activite activite;
}

public class cls_activite {
    public Integer statut;  
}
}
```

I need to call this class and set the value in another class, in a method :

```
    CalloutWS calloutWS = new CalloutWS();

    calloutWS.dateEffet = Date.today();
    List<CalloutWS.cls_post> postulants = new List<CalloutWS.cls_post>();
    CalloutWS.cls_activite activitePost1 = new CalloutWS.cls_activite();
    CalloutWS.cls_post post1 = new CalloutWS.cls_post();
    post1.num= 1;
    post1.date = Date.valueOf(dateNaissance);
    post1.activite = activitePost1;
    activitePostulant1.statut = 62;
    postulants.add(post1);
```

The problem here is that only `dateEffet` ispart of the instance of calloutWS, `calloutWS`. It seems simple, but how can I make `postulants` and `activitePost1` part of the instance ? I tried to make something like that :

```
calloutWS.cls_activite = new CalloutWS.cls_activite();
```

But that doesn't work either (does not compile).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an instance variable of type `List<CalloutWS.cls_post>`; it's `posts`. Note that `List<CalloutWS.cls_post>` and `cls_post[]` (within `CalloutWS`) are equivalent types, because `cls_post` is an inner class. You can assign

```
calloutWS.posts = postulants
```

Note that your variable name `calloutWS` shadows your class name `CalloutWS`. Apex is not case-sensitive. To avoid very confusing errors, change your variable name.

You do not have an instance variable of type `cls_activite`. You would need to create one to assign it. The compiler is reading

```
calloutWS.cls_activite = new CalloutWS.cls_activite();
```

as an attempt to assign to an inner class, which is not legal or what you intend to do.

However, you have an instance variable in the inner class `cls_post` that already holds the `cls_activite` value `activitePost1`.

Comment: thanks for the answer and the tip for the name of the class ! I will change it then

Answer (score 4):

calloutWS has a variable called as `posts`. You have to initialize it with 'postulants'. Thus your code will be

```
calloutWS.posts = postulants;
```

That being said, you are doing so much work in the service class.A bettwer work would be to define constructor and pass values through them.

```
public with sharing class CalloutWS{
    public Date dateEffet {get; set;}
    public cls_post[] posts {get; set;}


    CalloutWS(Date dateEffet ,cls_post [] posts){
        this. dateEffet = dateEffet;
        this.posts = posts;
    }
    public class cls_post {
        public Integer num;
        public Date date;   
        public cls_activite activite;

        cls_post(Integer num ,Date date,cls_activite activite){
            this.num = num;
            this.date = date;
            this.activite = activite;
        }
    }

    public class cls_activite {
        public Integer statut;  

        cls_activite (Integer statut){
            this.statut = statut;
        }

    }
}
```

Thus your implementation code will be of 3 lines.

```
CalloutWS.cls_activite activite =new CalloutWS.cls_activite(62);
CalloutWS.cls_post postulant = new CalloutWS.cls_post(1, Date.valueOf(dateNaissance),1);
CalloutWS calloutWS = new CalloutWS(Date.today(),new List<CalloutWS.cls_post>{postulant});
```

Comment: Dear downvoters would love to understand reasons for your downvotes

Comment: Have my upvote to balance it out.

Comment: Ill bite. I downvoted since when you first posted it, it was just a code dump. Looks like you've polished it out since.

Comment: I might have posted as answer instead of saving as a draft. My bad :/